# Select Fields Contain a Percentage Sign (%) in SQL

Tags: sql-server

I need a SELECT statement that will return all rows where a given field contains a percentage sign (%).

I've tried the following but it just pulls out all records:

```
select * from MyTable where MyColumn LIKE '%%%'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Escape using **[] bracket symbol**

```
select * from MyTable where MyColumn LIKE '%[%]%'
```

or by using **ESCAPE keyword**

```
 select * from MyTable where MyColumn LIKE '%\%%' ESCAPE '\'
```

Comment: If someone else needed, `'` can be escaped by adding one more in front of it. e.g., `''`

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 ways to escape these wild cards.

1. You can use the default square braces “[]” like this- [%] or [_]
2. You can define your own escape character by using the keyword ESCAPE at the end of your where clause.

Ex. select * from name_column where name like ‘gyan_sagar’ ESCAPE ‘\’

In the example above we escape “_” by defining “\” as an escape character using the ESCAPE keyword.

Note: You can only define a single character for escaping and not a string.

Answer (score 0):

You can search any special charecters by using this

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE email LIKE '%[^0-9a-zA-Z @\.\-]%'
```